# Bounded function $f \colon \mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ that does not achieve absolute extremum

Tags: real-analysis

> Find an example of a bounded function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that does not achieve an absolute minimum nor an absolute maximum on $\mathbb R$

How is this possible? If $f(x) = x$, it does not achieve an absolute min nor abs max on $\mathbb R$ (or does it?) but is the function bounded? If $f(x) = 5$ or any constant number in $\mathbb R$, has this function achieved abs min and abs max (abs min=abs max)? and Is this $f$ bounded?

Please help me here. Thank you very much!

Comment: The simple approach is horizontal asymptotes above and below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example to broaden your thinking:
$$f(x)=\begin {cases}\frac 12 & x \in \Bbb Z\\
x-\lfloor x \rfloor & x \not \in \Bbb Z \end {cases}$$
This is bounded between $0$ and $1$ but achieves neither.  It is not continuous, but we were not asked for that.  It is a fine function, delivering a single output for every input in the domain.

Another, with a slightly different idea
$$f(x)=\begin {cases} 0&x \not \in \Bbb Z\\
1-2^{-x}&x \gt 0, x\in \Bbb Z\\
-1+2^x&x \lt 0, x \in \Bbb Z \end {cases}$$
On the positive side you have a series of points approaching $1$.  On the negative side you have a series of points approaching $-1$.  Neither is achieved.

Answer (score 6):

$f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ means "to", not "onto", so $f(x)=\arctan x$ is a good example.